# Generic Invoke of WCF services

Tags: wcf, methods

I'm trying to create some tool for testing WCF services. I'm aware of such products, but the goal is creating of mine one.
 Main trouble is in calling wcf methods without having contracts. I've found solutions using scvutil.exe, but I need to make it on the on demand, as soon as I receive service address.
 Any advices or links are appreciated.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio provides a tool (the WcfTestClient) that will create a proxy for any **WSDL** based service (it doesn't have to be a WCF service). There are a few limitations with enumerations as data types and a few other quirks but it's a very useful tool. Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) for the tool.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I'm looking for solution to create smth like this testing tool - that's my goal. Adding the plus, but can't mark it as answer.